# Interaction between two objects of the same type

Tags: java, nodes, communication

I have created an object "Node" with two parameters: hostName (string) and serviceList(a list of strings).

I have also written a class that manages:

- registration of an object Node to a server, creating a Map of Nodes/Ports and returning the port where the node is registered
- search for a single service among all the serviceLists already registered to the server

Now, I need to go further and create a connection between two nodes, with one node that uses a service that the other node has registered. I've written another class called "ArithmeticService" that contains four simple methods, "add" "substract" "multiply" and "divide", each one simply returning the respective operation between two longs.

```
public class ArithmeticServiceHandler implements ArithmeticService.Iface {
  @Override
  public long add(int num1, int num2) throws TException {
    return num1 + num2;
  }

  @Override
  public long multiply(int num1, int num2) throws TException {
    return num1 * num2;
  }

  @Override
  public long substract(int num1, int num2) throws TException {
    return num1 - num2;
  }

  @Override
  public long divide(int num1, int num2) throws TException {
    return num1 / num2;
  }

}
```

So, I want in my test to have (for starting) two nodes registered with their respective serviceLists, where services are one or more of the arithmetical operations of ArithmeticService, then one node asks for a service it needs, finds that the other node has it, establishes a connection with the second node and uses the service it needs.

My difficulty is understanding how the connection can be established, and how the asking node can use the service it asks for.

For example, do I have to rewrite the object "Node", considering that it must have also variables in order to use the asked service?

Do I have to write a method "useService" (first name coming to my mind), which returns the operation asked?

edit: adding the code i use to establish connection

```
public static class ManagementServer extends Server {

    public ManagementServer(int port) {
        super(port);
    }
}

private Server server;
private TTransport transport;
private TProtocol protocol;
private ManagementService.Client client;

public abstract static class Server implements Runnable {

    private TServer tserver;
    private int port;

    public Server(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            TServerSocket serverTransport = new TServerSocket(port);

            ManagementService.Processor<ManagementServiceHandler> generateProcessor = new ManagementService.Processor<ManagementServiceHandler>(new ManagementServiceHandler());

            tserver = new TThreadPoolServer(new TThreadPoolServer.Args(serverTransport).
                    processor(generateProcessor));
            System.out.println("Starting server on port: " + port + "...");
            tserver.serve();
        } catch (TTransportException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void unserve() {
        tserver.stop();
    }
}

@Before
public void initializeManagementServer() throws Exception {

    server = new ManagementServer(7911);
    server.start();

    Thread.sleep(200);
    transport = new TSocket("localhost", 7911);
    protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
    client = new ManagementService.Client(protocol);
    transport.open();
}

@Test
...
...
...

@After
public void teardownManagementServer() throws Exception {
    transport.close();
    server.unserve();           
}
}
```

Comment: Are the objects connected over the network? If so, please provide some more code showing how the connection is established

Comment: edited first post. Right now, i'm working only locally.